# Merging two dictionaries of different sizes and different values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have two different dictionaries I have created from Queries of different sizes

```
dictionary1:
{'id': 1 , 'passCount': 3}, {'id': 2 , 'passCount': 4}, {'id': 5 , 'passCount': 7}, {'id': 6, 'passCount': 3}

dictionary2: 
{'id': 1 , 'failCount': 1}, {'id': 3 , 'failCount': 2}, {'id': 5 , 'failCount': 3}
```

Originally, I created a master list from these two dictionaries:

```
List = []
for i in dictionary1:
for j in dictionary2:
    if i['id'] = j['id]:
       List.append[i['id'],i['passCount'],j['failCount']]
    else:
       List.append[i['id'],i['passCount'],0]
       List.append[j['id'],0, j['failCount']
return List
```

When I would print this List out for my data, I would only get a List of id's that match, and would not take into account the other ones.

For that reason I want to print a dictionary where I could get it to print

`{'id' = 1, 'passCount' = 3, 'failCount' = 1}, {'id': 2 , 'passCount': 4, 'failCount' = 0}...` and so on without deleting any of the id's

Thanks

Comment: the structure containing `dictionary1`, `dictionary2` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution using [***dict.setdefault***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and [***dict.update***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) methods:

```
l1 = [{'id': 1 , 'passCount': 3}, {'id': 2 , 'passCount': 4}, {'id': 5 , 'passCount': 7}, {'id': 6, 'passCount': 3}]
l2 = [{'id': 1 , 'failCount': 1}, {'id': 3 , 'failCount': 2}, {'id': 5 , 'failCount': 3}]

grouped = {}
for d in l1+l2:
    grouped.setdefault(d['id'], {'failCount':0, 'passCount': 0}).update(d)

result = [d for d in grouped.values()]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'passCount': 3, 'id': 1, 'failCount': 1}, {'passCount': 4, 'id': 2, 'failCount': 0}, {'passCount': 0, 'id': 3, 'failCount': 2}, {'passCount': 7, 'id': 5, 'failCount': 3}, {'passCount': 3, 'id': 6, 'failCount': 0}]
```

Comment: only unfortunate part is that for 'id': 3, the 'passCount' should be 'passCount' = 0 instead of not having it there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they're two different **lists** ,not dictionaries,so I assume they're two lists:

`failCount` set to 0 by default,you can try this:

```
a=[{'id': 1 , 'passCount': 3}, {'id': 2 , 'passCount': 4}, {'id': 5 , 'passCount': 7}, {'id': 6, 'passCount': 3}]
b=[{'id': 1 , 'failCount': 1}, {'id': 3 , 'failCount': 2}, {'id': 5 , 'failCount': 3}]

for j in a:
    j.update({'failCount': 0})
    for i in b:
        if i["id"]==j["id"]:
            j.update(i)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'passCount': 3, 'failCount': 1}, {'id': 2, 'passCount': 4, 'failCount': 0}, {'id': 5, 'passCount': 7, 'failCount': 3}, {'id': 6, 'passCount': 3, 'failCount': 0}]
```

Comment: Any possibility of let's say there isn't a 'failCount' for that specific id, to arbitrarily set it to 0? and print out

{'id': 2 , 'passCount': 4, 'failCount': 0}